# The soft heap contains at most n/2 power r-3 corrupted items at any given time. How is that so?

Tags: algorithm, heap, priority-queue, min-heap, soft-heap

In [this paper published by Bernard Chazelle](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Echazelle/pubs/sheap.pdf), one of the lemmas (Lemma 5.2) states that "the soft heap contains at most `n / 2^(r-3)` corrupted items at any given time." I am struggling to understand it. It would be helpful if anyone can explain how it is so.